# C# vs Delphi- both codes are giving different value for ‰

Tags: c#, delphi, delphi-7

Can anyone tell me that why am I getting different values for ‰ symbol?
My Delphi7 code is-

```
k := ord('‰'); //k is of type longint; receiving k as 137
```

My C# code is-

```
k = (long)('‰');//k is of type long; receiving k as 8240
```

Please give me a solution, that how can I get the same value in C#? Because Delphi code solves my purpose.

Comment: I reverted your question edit. Please let's concentrate on this question before we move on to another question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C# encodes text as UTF-16. Delphi 7 encodes text as ANSI. Therein lies the difference. You are not comparing like with like.

You ask how to get the ANSI ordinal value for that character. Use `new Encoding(codepage)` to get an `Encoding` instance that matches your Delphi ANSI encoding. You'll need to know which code page you are using in order to do that. Then call `GetBytes` on that encoding instance.

For instance if your code page is 1252 then you'd write:

```
enc = new Encoding(1252);
byte[] bytes = enc.GetBytes("‰");
```

Or if you want to use the default system ANSI encoding you would use

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("‰");
```

One wonders why you are asking this question. Have answered many questions here, I wonder if you are performing some sort of encryption, hashing or encoding, and are using as your reference some Delphi code that uses `AnsiString` variables as byte arrays. In which case, whilst `Encoding.GetBytes` is what you asked for, it's not what you need. What you need is to stop using strings to hold binary data. Use byte arrays. In both Delphi and C#.

Comment: Yes I meant (long)'‰'

Comment: How can I get to know the value of codepage as Delphi code is written by third party?

Comment: `Encoding.Default` is an encoding for the os active codepage. That matches your Delphi code. What is the code trying to do?

Comment: Added the Delphi code. Now please tell me how to do the same in C#?

Comment: I answered the question that you asked

Comment: But to translate that delphi code to C# use `Encoding.Default.GetBytes` on the whole string and then operate on the byte array. That said the Delphi code is making the exact mistake that I described in my final paragraph and using a string to hold binary data. Unfortunately there seems to be an endless supply of Delphi programmers who make this mistake.

Comment: byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("‰"); worked for me. Thanks.